# How can I override SocketChannelImpl class in order to use the same FileDescriptor in two different SocketChannelImpl objects?

Tags: java

I want to override the JDK implementation of sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl so I have access to the FileDescriptor and can create a second SocketChannelImpl with an existing FileDescriptor.

I can't quite seem to figure out how to force my instance of SocketChannelImpl to load in the VM before the JDK version.  I also can't seem to find any instance of someone doing the same thing.

Do I have to build the rt.jar and swap in my version?

**UPDATE**:  Just wanted everyone to know that I am still looking into this issue.  I know that the Java VM prevents any forced modification to things like the Selector and have not yet tried an experiment with the SocketChannelImpl (having to change the top level class WindowsAsynchonousSocketChannelImpl) and the default Provider to get this behavior.  I will repost in here if when I find out more about what Java will and won't let you do in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/nio/ch/SocketChannelImpl.java.html the SocketChannelImpl class is not final, it has a public getter for the FileDescriptor property and a package-private constructor that accepts a FileDescriptor.

Hence you should be able to retrieve an existing FileDescriptor from one SocketChannelImpl and either:

- extend the SocketChannelImpl and create a constructor that passes a given FileDescriptor to the super class' constructor, or
- use Reflection API to retrieve a package-private constructor and use it to create a new instance of SocketChannelImpl.

Comment: You really should mention the first way is strongly preferred.